# Noob question: multiple parameters for custom function in powershell

Tags: powershell

I try to simply pass two parameters to a powershell function. The seccond parameter $args keeps being empty in the function. What am I missing?

```
$t= "wi-fi Adapter"

if (multilike $t "*wi-fi*,*wireless*,*wan miniport*" ) {
    Write-Host "True"
}

function multilike($text, $args) {
    foreach ($arg in $args.split) {
        if ($text -like $arg) {return $true}
    }
    return $false
}
```

Comment: `$args.split` -> `$args.split()`, although you might want to use a variable name _other than_ `args`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

### Don't use `$args`

`$args` is [an automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1), using it as a declared parameter might result in unexpected behavior

### Remember to invoke `Split()`

`$someString.Split` is going to emit the method signatures of the `String.Split()` method overloads - in order to actuall execute the method, you need to supply a(n empty) parameter list:

```
function multilike($text, $patterns) {
    foreach($pattern in $patterns.Split())
    { # ...
```

---

Since you want to accept *one-or-more* strings as your second parameter argument, you might benefit from declaring it an array of strings:

```
function multilike {
  param(
    [string]$text, 
    [string[]]$patterns
  )
    foreach($pattern in $patterns) # no need to .Split() any longer
    { # ...
```

And then call like:

```
multilike $t *wi-fi*,*wireless*,"*wan miniport*"
```

Comment: Great, thank you!
The occupied name "$args" made me doubt my mind. 
Also nice solution with the array of strings.